# Edge bridge not equal

Tags: mesh

How is this possible, I'm doing an edge bridge and one side is concave and the other side is convex.
They should both be hollow like (the green one).
Everything is correct, such as scale, normals, deleted loos, merged by distance, etc.

[image]

Comment: Hey :). The bridge edge loops tool has some known issues. Since your object looks like a spiked wheel, you may want to use Array modifier - model one part, the others will be generated automatically :).

Comment: Thanks, with LoopTools it works.